# Boostrap dropdown link is not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when I click on link in mobile it is not working.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Elaborate more, when you say mobile, in every platform or only in iOS?
Also, have you tried to see if there is any error in console?

Comment: it happening only in mobile also in ios and there is no any error in a console it works fine in desktop

Comment: Did you test it on real devices or in browser emulator?

Comment: yes! its not working